# Each $X_\alpha$ is homeomorphic to a closed set in $\Pi_{\alpha \in A} X_\alpha$

Tags: general-topology, product-space

I am trying to show that if each $(X_\alpha, \tau_\alpha)$ is $T_2$ and $\Pi_{\alpha \in A} X_\alpha$ is complete, then each factor $X_\alpha$ is homeomorphic to a closed subspace of the product.

Let $\alpha_0\in A$ and consider $A_{\alpha_0}$, I was thinking of constructing the set $\Pi_{\alpha\in A} K_\alpha$ where $K_\alpha$ is a singleton when $\alpha \neq 0$ and $K_\alpha = X_\alpha$ when $\alpha = \alpha_0$. Certainly $A_{\alpha_0}$ is homeomorphic to this subset. But I am not sure if this set is closed ... is this the case?

On one hand I want to say it is closed since if you take a convergent net in the constructed set, it must converge inside the constructed set.

On the other hand I want to say it is not closed, since if you consider the complement, I can't fit a basic open set inside.

Comment: The projection $\pi_{\alpha_0} \colon \prod K_{\alpha} \to X_{\alpha_0}$ and its inverse are both uniformly continuous. Hence $\prod K_{\alpha}$ is complete iff $X_{\alpha_0}$ is complete.

Comment: Yes it is closed.  As each space is closed and every point in every space is closed

Comment: Yes it is closed as it is the product of closed sets.  It is as simple as that and  only requires the spaces to be T_1 and none of them empty.  Exercise:  show a product of closed sets is closed.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Take a point which is not in $\prod_\alpha K_\alpha$. Can you construct an open set around it not intersecting $\prod_\alpha K_\alpha$? (Maybe using the fact that your spaces are $T_2$...)

Comment: I know that singletons are closed, so their complements are open, but if we want a basic open set around our point not intersecting $\Pi K_\alpha$ we can't since a basic open set can be different from the factor spaces only finitely often.

Comment: @GrEg "Singletons are closed" is $T_1$, you want to use $T_2$.

Comment: Do we just use that the product is $T_2$? If a point is in the complement then take any point inside of $\Pi K_\alpha$. They are not the same, so by $T_2$-ness we get open sets separating them. The open set around the point in the complement will then be disjoint from $Pi K_\alpha$...?